# Variation with binom and the other method in R

Tags: r

Apologies if this problem is simple.
Imagine that we have 20 balls chosen at probability of `0.5+1:20/50`.

```
P=0.5+1:20/50
ONE=function(M,n) {
        N=1:n
        m=length(M)
        for(j in 1:n) {
            N[j]=sum(runif(m)<M)
        }
        N
    }

mean.1=mean(ONE(P,100000))
mean.2=mean(rbinom(100000,size=20,prob=P))
```

Easily seen here, that both are equal using both methods. But when I want to calculate P(X<=5), where X means the number of balls chosen, something odd happened:

```
ONE.p=function(M,n) {
        N=1:n
        m=length(M)
        for(j in 1:n) {
            N[j]=sum(runif(m)<M)
        }
        sum(N<=5)/n
    }
p.1=ONE.p(P,100000)
p.2=sum(rbinom(100000,size=20,prob=P)<=5)/100000
```

Here, `p.1` is almost `0`, but `p.2` is estimated at `e-3` level. Using `hist()`, we can see:

```
hist(ONE(P,100000))
hist(rbinom(100000,size=20,prob=P))
```

The second one is wider. I thought these two provide the same calculation.But I am confused with the results. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: From this: `rbinom(30,10,rep(c(0,1),each=5)`. I kinda have some clue, but my head just hurts thinking so long. So, it will help, but I am not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between the number of observations and the number of the trials per observation. `rbinom` assumes that within each observation, the probability is the same, but the probability can be different between different observations. In your `ONE` function, you assume exactly the oposite. Here's a small example of this difference:

```
# 2 observations of size 2. 
# in the first observation, both trials have 0 probability, 
# in the second observation, both trials have probability 1. 
rbinom(2, 2, 0:1) 
# replicate 2 observations of size 1 twice.  
replicate(2, sum(rbinom(2, 1, 0:1)))
```

The mean is the same, because the sum is the same.

```
Nsims <- 100000
sum(rbinom(Nsims*20, 1, prob=P))
sum(rbinom(20, Nsims, prob=P))
sum(rbinom(Nsims, 20, prob=P))
# this is different because it only uses P[1]
sum(rbinom(1, 20*Nsims, prob=P))
```

So if you would like to do what your function does with `rbinom`, here's how this would look like:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
Nsims <- 100000
df <- data.frame(v.ONE = ONE(P,Nsims),
                 v.replicate = replicate(Nsims, sum(rbinom(20, size=1, prob=P))), 
                 v.size20 = rbinom(Nsims, size=20, prob=P))
df.melt <- melt(df, measure.vars=c("v.ONE", "v.replicate", "v.size20"))
ggplot(df.melt, aes(factor(value), fill=variable)) + geom_histogram(position="dodge")
```